# How are you organizing your $HOME?

Tags: shell, home

I've always wanted to know more about how people (power users and lambda users) were organizing there `$HOME`. The trend is currently is using `xdg-users-dirs` which define a set of *most used* folders like : `Music/`, `Video/`, `Documents/`, …

As a lot of geeks or developers or sysadmin, I do tweak a lot my shells and I do wrote a lot of scripts. The thing is :

- Where do you usually put your scripts ?
- Where do you usually put the lib that is common for a lot of your scripts and ?
- What about docs or man ?

For example, for a long time, I did put everything in a `$HOME/.local` folder that was more or less like `/usr/local` (You could find `bin/`, `lib/`, `share/`, `docs/`, `logs/`). I'm thinking to not bother with the `.local/` and put everything on home but I was wondering how people deal with that.

Comment: I do exactly that and it works fine. I have `bin etc local share src tmp var` in my home dir and link `~/etc/foo` to `~/.foo`. This is great for version control and compiling to home dir on systems where I can't anywhere else. I mostly just have to edit `PREFIX` in `config.mk` to say `$(HOME)` or `$(HOME)/local` and I'm ready to go.